# Is this the correct less refactor?

Tags: css, refactoring, less

I am trying to convert my css to less but the online tools are not showing any restructuring. The following snippet is not showing any reduced output.

.tax-included .tax-included-show { display: none;}

I seem to recall that this can be reduced further with operators but I can't get it working.

These did not work as expected

```
.tax-included { 
   &-show {
 display: none;
   }
 }
```

```
 .tax-included {
 > &-show {
display: none;
   }
}
```

Basically, I shouldn't need to type 'tax-included' two times.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restructure it further with the following code:

```
.tax {
    &-included {
        & &-show {
            display: inline;
        }
    }
}`
```

Output:

```
.tax-included .tax-included-show {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with explanation as to why this solves the issue, and including relevant  links to documentation

Comment: @Harrison Thank you for the comment. Basically, I've added the snippet which rendered the output I wanted.